# Windows 8.1 fails to optimize System Reserved partition

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-8.1, ntfs, trim

I have Windows 8.1 Professional x64 running from a 256GB OCZ Vertex 4 SSD.

Windows has divided the drive in to two partitions:

1. System Reserved (350MB NTFS)
2. C: (238.13GB NTFS)

Whenever Windows attempts to optimize the System Reserved partition, I get an error in the event log:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Defrag
Date:          1/29/2014 11:07:54 AM
Event ID:      257
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      My_Computer
Description:
The volume System Reserved was not optimized because an error was encountered: The parameter is incorrect. (0x80070057)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Defrag" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">257</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-29T17:07:54.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62696</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>My_Computer</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>System Reserved</Data>
    <Data>The parameter is incorrect. (0x80070057)</Data>
    <Binary>00000000A40500005105000000000000629468641336AAB85B55B1B5B038000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Should I just remove this from the list of items that are on the optimize schedule or is there a way to fix this issue such that the optimization can succeed?

Not only on SSD but also on Hard Drive the problem exists:
[image: System Reserved Needs Optimization]

Comment: It's an SSD. It doesn't get defragmented; it gets "optimized" (TRIM, I think). And that's just the way Windows set things up. In "Optimize Drives" it says the "System Reserved" drive "Needs optimization". I do not know why Windows thinks it needs optimization.

Comment: The event just says that an application called Microsoft-Windows-Defrag failed to optimize a drive. Not that the particular optimization it tried to apply was defragmenting.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have HDD. It won't optimize even if the message states: SYSTEM RESERVED HARD DISC Needs Optimization (36% fragmented)